# How to properly clean a bathroom fan?

Tags: bathroom, cleaning, exhaust-fan

I recently pulled off the grille and cleaned a filthy bathroom fan. I noticed the fan's pull is not nearly good as it once was. I didn't really have an approach - I didn't remove the fan, for instance, but just hit it here and there with a vaccuum to remove dust clumps. It didn't make a noticeable difference.

Do I need to fully remove the fan and check the duct and the exit vent?

Also how can one tell when a bathroom fan has given up the ghost and simply needs to be replaced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fans should be cleaned regularly to maintain performance. For the main bathroom, this is probably every year. For occasional use bathrooms, every few years is probably fine. A fan only needs replacement if it's noisy or completely inoperative.

Here's my annual routine. You probably won't be working directly with wiring, but consider turning off the breaker for safety. At a minimum turn off the wall switch.

1. Remove the grille and/or bulb housing/plate. This will either be with some spring hooks, tabs on the sides of a light cover, an acorn nut behind a light cover, or other simple mechanisms. Basically you want to open up the main fan housing for access to the motor. If there's a full-size bulb here you'll probably want to remove it.
2. At this point you should see the fan motor and fan (usually a "squirrel cage", but maybe a simple bladed type). It's probably attached to a plate spanning part or all of the upper portion of the fan housing. It'll be secured with one or two screws, or a tab that engages the housing wall, or both. Detach that plate and unplug any cords in the area to free it.
3. Now you start the actual cleaning. Soak the plastic grille and/or light cover. Vacuum loose dust from all accessible surfaces. Rub and wipe dust buildup off the flapper and duct connection. This part's mostly common sense, so do your best. If you can see it, clean it.
4. Clean the fan itself. Ideally there's a C-clip or other device holding the plastic fan rotor onto the motor shaft. If possible, detach that. Soak and clean the rotor. Avoid wetting the motor itself. If you can't detach the rotor, use gentle scraping tools to de-crud it, then wipe it with a damp cloth. Try to get all surfaces clean as their shape is critical to good exhaust function.
5. Wipe everything dry. If the motor was inadvertently wetted beyond a few drops of splatter, shake it off and set it aside to dry for a few hours.
6. Inspect all components for damage. Make sure the flapper operates freely and closes properly. Check that the duct is still attached well. Replace or repair anything that needs it.
7. Reassemble in the reverse order.

---

One of my pet peeves is buzzing in poorly-designed bath fans. Here are some tips for reducing noise in an otherwise functional fan. You may want to implement them while your fan is apart and clean.

- Install cushioning behind covers and between parts. Self-stick felt pads, for example, come in many sizes.
- Silicone caulk is a great de-noisifier. I've used it copiously in some cases to silence folded sheet metal components with overlapping portions that vibrate against each other. You wouldn't do this for parts that need to come apart later, though.
- If you're *installing* a new fan, try to decouple it from framing. The worst source of noise is sometimes the 50/60Hz hum inherent in AC motors, which can pervade adjacent rooms as well. If you can isolate the fan from the ceiling joist, for example, you'll greatly reduce that hum.
- Buy a quality fan, but don't trust the "sones" number--this seems to only refer to airflow sound and not motor hum. Seek actual user reviews to learn whether a fan is truly quiet.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the ghost-giving-up part of your question, you can buy a cheap anemometer online to measure actual air flow.

Fans are marketed with CFM ratings.  You can't take marketing too literally, nor can you rely too much on the calibration of a cheap instrument.  So.  If you can find a bathroom fan that is new, and properly installed, and measure it with your new meter to see what actual reading you get compared to its published rating, that will help you to understand what to expect from your own old and new fans.